# Please someone explain me css positioning properties in easy to understand plain english?

Tags: css, layout

Please someone explain me css positioning properties in easy to understand plain english?

With examples.

I have been struggling to understand how css positioning work in creating a layout and alignment.

Answer (score 4):

A quick search on Google has lead me to this: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: AFAIK this is the best positioning tutorial. I myself learned css positioning from that one. +1

Comment: the most simple tutorial to immediately understand positioning

Answer (score 1):

While there are many tutorials on CSS positioning such as

http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/
http://www.tizag.com/cssT/position.php
http://www.mako4css.com/Tutorial.htm

The problem is that there are a number of ways to position elements on a page, you can use float, position relative divs with absolute nested divs, then you have margins and padding, as well as negative margins. Heights and widths in pixels percentages etc. It's not something to learn from a single tutorial but rather experience.

My suggestion to you is install Chrome and use the developer tool on a basic CSS layout, or FireBug in firefox to learn how CSS works on simple layouts, here you can find many styles of CSS layouts to play with http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/